# Android wear app got rejected due to Bridging notification

Tags: android, android-wear-2.0, android-wear-notification

I recently published an Android Wear app that was rejected. I got the following message from Google Play Developers:

> The issue is with your bridge notifications, as this notification
>   is not enhanced. The notification simply contains text but does not
>   contain anything else that the user can interact with.

Initially I was just showing the notification with a text. After the first rejection I implemented two actions on the notification by which the user can interact with the notification. I resubmitted the application, but it was rejected again for the same reason.

Please help me out how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the bridge notification and resubmit the application of plays store. 
For disable the bridge notification used following code in wear application Androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.notificationBridgeMode"
    android:value="NO_BRIDGING" />
```

Please refer to this link https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/bridger